# Transaction confirmation time vs Slot time

Tags: rpc, validator

The slot time is around 600ms or so per https://explorer.solana.com/.
However, the confirmation times are highly unstable, and can take 10's of seconds per https://www.validators.app/ping-thing?locale=en&network=mainnet .

Could someone explain the main reasons why these numbers are so different? Why does it sometimes take so many blocks for transaction confirmation?

If a certain dapp wants a faster and more deterministic confirmation time, is there any recourse available to them, such as fee prioritization?

Answer (score 0):

The slot time currently is close t 400ms.
The variance of transaction confirmation time depends on the blockchain network load as well as on the transaction itself. For example, if there are many txs updating the same account, they cannot be parallelized and will be scheduled for the execution one after another.

Now you can [set up priority fee](https://docs.solana.com/proposals/fee_transaction_priority)